# Java Determine type T at runtime

Tags: java, jpa, arraylist

I have the following Java code;

```
PagedResponse<Person> response = new PagedResponse<Person>();
TypedQuery<Person> query = getNamedQuery("Person.findSpecific", Person.class);
response = executePagedTypedQuery(query);
```

Now executePagedTypedQuery is defined as;

```
protected <T> PagedResponse<T> executePagedTypedQuery(TypedQuery query) {

PagedResponse<T> response = new PagedResponse<T>();
List<T> resultList = query.getResultList();

}
```

Now I want that inside executePagedTypedQuery() method, the type T should be set to "Person", which is what I am passing.
But for some reason, on debugging, it says

```
T = >"T" is not a known variable in the current context.<
```

Am I passing the parameter incorrectly ?

Answer (score 1):

If you change the signature to

```
protected <T> PagedResponse<T> executePagedTypedQuery(TypedQuery<T> query)
```

then when you pass in your query, `T` will be chosen accordingly.

Comment: I did try that...it still says T = >"T" is not a known variable in the current context.<

Comment: Tell me which line that error comes up on.  Exactly what is on that line?

Comment: If I debug on the line List<T> resultList = query.getResultList();
it says T = >"T" is not a known variable in the current context.<

Comment: So this is something the debugger is reporting?  Does it work OK without the debugger?  I would expect that the debugger won't be able to tell you `T`, because of the type erasure.  The debugger will never see `T`.

Comment: Actually it does not work ahead...like I do not get the Person type

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that.  Are the objects in `resultList` not `Person` objects at the end?

Comment: How are you putting the `resultList` into the `response` anyway?

Comment: Yes the objects in resultList are not Person objects in the end...which is why I get a cast error later

Comment: when I try to iterate the response using for (Person person : resultList) {

Answer (score 0):

You're not invoking the method incorrectly; `T` is not passed as a parameter to the method.

Generics in Java are basically compile-time syntactic sugar to prevent you having to do lots of casts everywhere.  The compiler will generate the compiled code of the method assuming that all references to `T` are references to the maximal parent type `T` if it has a type constraint, or `Object` if it doesn't have a constraint.  This is called [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Contract this with the situation in C# - type parameters are actually accessible to your code, so you can write things like `new T();` or `typeof(T)` (equivalent to Java `T.class`) in your method.